# Putting out the title of every movie,

Tags: ruby, api, rubygems, command-line-interface

Recently I built a CLI Data Gem that listed and described all Star Wars movies, when I did my review with my cohort lead she asked me to build a method that puts out the title of every movie instance.

```
def say_titles
  Movie.all.each.with_index do |title|
    puts "#{movie.title}"
  end
end
```

this is what I currently have but can't seem to get it to work completely. Any ideas?

```
class Movie

attr_reader :title, :episode_id, :opening_crawl, :director, :producer, :release_date
  @@all = []

  def initialize(title, episode_id, opening_crawl, director, producer, release_date)
    @title = title
    @episode_id = episode_id
    @opening_crawl = opening_crawl
    @director = director
    @producer = producer
    @release_date = release_date
    @@all << self
  end

  def self.all
    @@all
  end

end
```

If needed, this is my whole Movie class...

Comment: "can't seem to get it to work completely" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with this bit:

```
Movie.all.each.with_index do |title|
  puts "#{movie.title}"
end
```

You're iterating through each `Movie` record, and using `title` as a placeholder, but then trying to refer to `#{movie.title}`. Whatever you use as the placeholder is what you'll be referring to each record as, so you can do:

```
Movie.all.each.with_index do |title|
  puts "#{title.title}"
end
```

Or you probably want:

```
Movie.all.each.with_index do |movie|
  puts "#{movie.title}"
end
```